# filtering sparse matrix with a vector of rownames

Tags: vector, filtering, sparse-matrix

I am tryin to filter a list of sparse matrices with a vector or rownames.
Somthing like this

List = list(a,b,c,d)
a,b,c,d are of class dgCmatrix and have the same rownames
I want to keep only rownames corresponding to my vector "vec"
I tried
List <- lapply(List,function(x) {
  rownames(x) <-  rownames(x) %in% vec
  x
})
I know the problem here is that "rownames(x) %in% vec" is a logical operation and doesnt return a vector or rownames but I dont know how to do it while keeping the list of dgCMatrix.
Hope my question is clear
Thanks for your help